# How to add class to html element in django-bootstrap3 template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using django-bootstrap3 (4.4.0) with django (0.16.1). Can anyone please tell me how will my template look after loading/extending the bootstrap3-template to get the following classes into html element:

```
<html  lang="en" class="js csstransforms csstransforms3d preserve3d">
```

Thanks,

Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem being solved:** How a child template (index.html) can modify class for html tag for its parent template (bootstrap3.html) in order to achieve this code of final html: `<html  lang="en" class="js csstransforms csstransforms3d preserve3d">`

**Solution:** In short, overriding the parent template allows me to modify it to my need, assuming that the original parent template (bootstrap3/bootstrap3.html, from django-bootstrap3 package) doesn't provide tags (knobs) to modify class of html tag.

```
# Directory structure
+myproject/templates/
            |-bootstrap3/bootstrap3.html
            |-index.html

# I simply copied the boostrap3.html from site-packages/bootstrap3/templates/bootstrap3/bootstrap3.html and edited as per my need as follows...
-<html{% if request.LANGUAGE_CODE %} lang="{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}"{% endif %}>
+<html{% if request.LANGUAGE_CODE %} lang="{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}"{% endif %} class="js csstransforms csstransforms3d preserve3d">

# In my index.html, I simply inherited my overriden bootstrap3.html
{% extends 'bootstrap3/bootstrap3.html' %}
{# ... #}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you be a little more clear with your question, by what i understand you have to define you sources like you do in regular css and js see this link for how to do define your source in Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Comment: I simply wanted to know how can I create a child template from bootstrap3.html as parent template by inheritance in order to allow the child to modify class of html tag. I realized, that can't be done unless you override the parent. Thats what I did and it works. Thanks for your help though